# Flask, Python and mongodb KeyError: 'Age' but the field Age exists in collection

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, crud

My collection:
db_operations = mongo.db.users

I'm creating an user with this method:

```
@app.route('/create')
def create():
    new_user = {'Name' : 'xyz', 'Age' : 20}
    db_operations.insert_one(new_user)
    #print(user['Name'],'Created successfully')
    result = {'result' : 'Created successfully'}
    return result
```

When i try to retrieve the users i created, i receive the error KeyError: 'Age' and nothing is displayed.

```
@app.route('/read')
def read():
    users = db_operations.find()
    output = [{'Name' : user['Name'], 'Age' : user['Age']} for user in users]
    #print(output)
    return jsonify(output)
```

Mongodb Atlas:
{"_id":{"$oid":"5fc22e0cade860ce44ec0541"},"Name":"xyz","Age":{"$numberInt":"20"}}

Another method, read-with-filter is working perfectly, is displaying the collection in browser.

```
@app.route('/read-with-filter')
def read_with_filter():
    filt = {'Name' : 'xyz'}
    users = db_operations.find(filt)
    output = [{'Name' : user['Name'], 'Age' : user['Age']} for user in users]
    #print(output)
    return jsonify(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error

```py
KeyError: 'Age'
```

it means that the key `Age` does not exist. In your case, it means that the variable `users` does not contain what you think it does. So the problem can, in my opinion, be only here

```py
users = db_operations.find()
```

Try to `print` the return out, e.g.

```py
print(db_operations.find())
```

or

```py
users = db_operations.find()
for user in users:
  print(user)
```

and you will probably solve the problem yourself.

HTH!